# Redirecting to routes defined outside current scope in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have a situation in my project where I need to build a route to a route defined outside the current scope. Let's say I have the following routing setup

```
/
/cars
/cars/buy
/cars/sell
/bikes
/bikes/buy
/bikes/sell
```

Now on my default routing I have defined that there are 3 routes /, /cars and /bikes. When /cars is activated i append the rotues /sell and /buy to the current route definintion. Now when the user is inside /cars/buy I would like to add a link like "Do you prefer to buy a bike instead?" and link to /bikes/buy.

Switching between buy/sell is done by

```
router.navigateToRoute('buy');
```

and

```
router.navigateToRoute('sell');
```

In the corresponding view-template.

So im kinda looking for something that would let me do

```
router.navigateToRoute('bikes);
router.navigateToRoute('buy');
```

In one move.

Comment: Can't you give the route a name e.g. the bikes/buy route could have a name called "buyBikes" you can then just navigate to that e.g router.navigateToRoute('buyBikes); (p.s. to give the route a name just add a name property when you set up the route)

Comment: Well the problem is that the buy route for bikes does not get declared until the /bikes route is activated. So technically the route does not exist yet.

Comment: You could declare the routes in app.js?

Comment: Sure, but that would defeat the purpose of using child-routers that I want to have in my project because of the deep levels of routing.

Comment: True. And I have wondered about this myself. If you work this out, I'd be interested to know how it was done. The gitter channel is quite good for asking questions too, might be worth asking there.

Comment: So, I have just tested this in my application. I have a child route set-up which is not initialised until you are in the view in question. I logged in, and pasted the url that it would navigate to directly into the url bar it navigated to it successfully. So this means you could navigate to the route directly (or use the route-href - http://aurelia.io/docs.html#generating-route-urls) but it means you have to know what the route is. Obviously if your route changes then you have to update the navigate call which may be something we just have to live with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can navigate directly to a route path (rather than a route name) using

```
router.navigate('route/href');
```

This will work even if child routes have not yet been registered (the router is smart enough to route to the child and wait for it to configure the router further before continuing)

In your case

```
router.navigate('bikes/buy');
```

from `cars/buy` should work fine

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thank you